# Why does JavaScript "style.display = 'block' change the width of my elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I have a `JavaScript` function to control showing/hiding certain selected pages with an event listener. The problem I'm having though is that the pages which are toggled to display are set to a much shorter width than they should be.

This is the function.

```js
function showPage(page) {
  document.querySelectorAll('tbody').forEach(tbody => {tbody.style.display = 'none';})
  document.querySelector(`#${page}`).style.display = 'block';
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
    button.onclick = function() {
      showPage(this.dataset.page);
    }           
  });
});
```

Here is a sample of the `HTML` it's working with.

```html
<tbody id="page1">
  {% for q in QBpage %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"></th>            
      <td>
        <h6>{{ q.player_name }}</h6>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-0 waves-effect"  onclick="myFunction('{{ player_data.player_name }} {{ player_data.position }}')">Add</button>
      </td>
      <td><h6> {{ q.team }} </h6></td>
      <td><h6> {{ q.position }}  </h6></td>
      <td><h6>{{ q.points }}</h6></td>
    </tr>          
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

As the function is targeting the `<tbody>` elements, I've tried to over-ride the styling of this element's `width`, but it's still no good despite the page attributes saying it's `width` is 100%. I've also found a few answers here on Stackoverflow that suggest changing `display = 'block'` to `display = 'table'` or `'inherit'` or any of the other values listed on [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp) but the `<tbody>` elements still display at a really small width. If anyone knows anything about this or can point me to a better answer here on the site, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<tbody>` elements, by default, display as `table-row-group`.

Setting it to any other value (like `block` or `table`) will put something between a `display: table` and a `display: table-row` that doesn't make sense.

Comment: You've saved my life. Now if I could only get the past couple of hours I've spent trying to fix this...